# Vnea 8ball pool league

Tags: rules, pool

It's my turn to shoot and the cue ball is touching one of my object balls is it legal for me to hit that ball straight on or does it have to be hit at an angle and what angle should it be hit at and if the balls aren't touching by the littlest of a eighth of an inch is it legal for me to hit that ball

Answer (score 2):

**If they are touching / frozen:**

If the cue ball is touching an object ball, then yes, it is legal to hit straight, or at an angle, into the object ball, assuming the shot then does one of the following (from [VNEA 8-Ball Rules](http://www.vnea.com/8-ball-rules.aspx)):

> **H. Fouling**
>
> **7. Object Ball Frozen To Cushion Or Cue Ball**
>
> This applies to any shot where the cue ball’s first contact with a ball is with one that is frozen to a cushion or to the cue ball itself. After the cue ball makes contact with the frozen ball, the shot must result in either:
>
> a) A ball being pocketed, or;
>
> b) The cue ball contacting a cushion, or;
>
> c) The frozen ball being caused to contact a cushion attached to a separate rail, or;
>
> d) Another object ball being caused to contact a cushion with which it was not already in contact.
>
> Failure to satisfy one of those four requirements is a foul.

---

**If they are not touching / frozen:**

It is still legal to play the shot, in the sense that it is not illegal to do so, however you are almost certainly going to perform a double hit (unless you hit the object ball *very* fine), which would result in a foul.